'PDE Export' has encountered a problem in Eclipse IDE when building the eclipsePlugin
I tried to build the following project using Ant, Java 1.8 in Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers of Version 2024-06 (4.32.0). But there is an error occurring as "'PDE Export' has encountered a problem in Eclipse IDE when building the eclipsePlugin". The details of the error as follows,
Project:
https://github.com/ibm-ecm/ibm-content-navigator-samples/tree/master/eclipsePlugin
Error:
A cycle was detected when generating the classpath com.ibm.ecm.icn.plugin_2.0.3, org.eclipse.ui_3.206.0.v20240524-2010, org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.132.0.v20240524-2010, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.16.400.v20240418-1547, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.17.400.v20240425-0840, org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.14.400.v20240427-1520, org.apache.batik.css_1.17.0.v20231215-1130, org.apache.xmlgraphics_2.9.0.v20230916-1600, org.apache.commons.logging_1.2.0.v20180409-1502, org.apache.log4j_1.2.25, javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615, javax.activation_1.1.0.v201211130549, javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.
Environments used:
Java: 1.8
IDE: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers
IDE Version: 2024-06 (4.32.0)
Build: Apache Ant
Build Version: 1.10.15
Attchements:

Can you please help me to resolve this?
First, I tried to check on "Allow for binary cycles in target platform", but I cannot find the place in IDE.
Second, I tried to check OFF "Use class files compiled in the workspace", unfortunately I cannot find the place in IDE.
And I browsed but didn't find a proper way to resolve this.

That project hasn't been updated in 7 years and is using PDE Export which is no longer maintained. It probably needs significant updating to work with modern versions of Eclipse. It looks like it was intended for Eclipse Oxygen (4.7), you could perhaps try building using that.

Hi @greg-449, Yes, I got your point. Thank you for your feedback. But I want to develop the IBM Content Navigator Plugin. When I searched the sample projects, I was unable to find a good code base other than this. So that's why I try to build a plugin by following this sample project. For doing that Eclipse needs to add some IBM ICN related plugins. That's why I want to build this and get that plugin. Hope you understand my concern.
